# Error running Apache Camel

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I'm going through the tutorial here: [Apache Camel Report Incident Part 5](https://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident-part5.html)

I've copied and pasted the code in the tutorial but am getting this error when I type `> mvn test` or 
`> mvn jetty:run`

```
[ERROR] Failed startup of context 
org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@785b38d6{
/camel-example-reportincident,C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Gravity\
camel-example-reportincident\src\main\webapp} 
org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: 
cxf://http://localhost:8080/part-five/webservices/incident?
    serviceClass=org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.ReportIncidentEndpoint
    &wsdlURL=report_incident.wsdl, 
please check your classpath contains the needed camel component jar.
```

I'm not sure which JAR is meant here, and would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to include the camel-cxf dependency to your project...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but my url was just a standard http request but i needed to include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```